# How to add a custom field in dokan new product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I'm looking for a way to add a custom field to my Dokan shop on wordpress.
I want to give vendors the option to add a short MP3 demo to display on their product page.

Any ideas how can this be done?

Also if you know how to remove that "Tag" option with a code snippet or somehting it would be great, sadly it has no css to hide it.

thank you for your time!

[Upload New Product in Dokan image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x3K0.jpg)

[Product Page on front end image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLUEJ.jpg)

Comment: You can try this article https://nayemdevs.com/how-to-add-a-new-field-on-product-upload-form-dokan-multivendor/

Comment: Try this:https://therichpost.com/how-to-add-new-custom-fields-in-dokan-product-form/